# x64 asm ret lands in no mans land

Tags: winapi, assembly, 64-bit, callstack

I assumed I had push'ed something without popping it, or vice versa, but I can't find anything wrong! I write to the console with a call to a dll that links properly, and I inexplicably am in no mans land... (address 0x0000000000000000)

I've put some sleeps in, and I'm sure that the api call WriteConsoleA is returning. It's on my last ret under the print function.

Any ideas?

.exe:

```
extern FreeConsole
extern Sleep
extern ExitProcess

extern print
extern newconsole
extern strlen

section .data BITS 64
        title:  db 'Consolas!',0

        message: db 'Hello, world',0,0

section .text bits 64
global Start
Start:
        mov rcx, title
        call newconsole
        mov rcx, 1000
        call Sleep

        mov rcx, message
        call print

        mov rcx, 10000
        call Sleep
        call FreeConsole
        xor rcx, rcx
        call ExitProcess
```

.dll:

```
extern AllocConsole
extern SetConsoleTitleA
extern GetStdHandle
extern WriteConsoleA
extern Sleep

export newconsole
export strlen
export print

section .data BITS 64
console.writehandle:     dq 0
console.readhandle:              dq 0
console.write.result:    dq 0

section .text BITS 64
global strlen
strlen:
        push rax
        push rdx
        push rdi

        mov rdi, rcx
        xor rax, rax
        mov rcx, dword -1
        cld

        repnz scasb
        neg rcx
        sub rcx, 2

        pop rdi
        pop rdx
        pop rax
        ret

global print
print:
        mov rbp, rsp
        push rcx
        call strlen

        mov r8, rcx
        pop rdx
        mov rcx, [console.writehandle]
        mov r9, console.write.result
        push qword 0
        call WriteConsoleA
        ret

global newconsole
newconsole:
        push rax
        push rcx
        call AllocConsole
        pop rcx
        call SetConsoleTitleA
        mov rcx, -11
        call GetStdHandle
        mov [console.writehandle], rax
        pop rax
        ret
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're talking about this function:

```
global print
print:
        mov rbp, rsp
        push rcx
        call strlen

        mov r8, rcx
        pop rdx
        mov rcx, [console.writehandle]
        mov r9, console.write.result
        push qword 0
        call WriteConsoleA
        ret
```

The x64 ABI requires that stack space is reserved even for parameters passed in registers.  `WriteConsoleA` is free to use those stack locations for whatever it wants - so you need to make sure that you've adjusted the stack appropriately.  As it stands, you're pushing only the last reserved pointer parameter. I think something like the following will do the trick for you:

```
        push qword 0
        sub rsp, 4 * 8  // reserve stack for register parameters
        call WriteConsoleA
        mov rsp, rbp    // restore rsp
        ret
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx (emphasis added):

> The x64 Application Binary Interface (ABI) is a 4 register fast-call calling convention, **with stack-backing for those registers**.
>
> ...
>
> The caller is responsible for allocating space for parameters to the callee, and must always allocate sufficient space for the 4 register parameters, even if the callee doesn’t have that many parameters.

Comment: And I'd suggest using a different name than `strlen` for your own function if it doesn't use the standard ABI and semantics - I spent a little too much time wondering why you didn't use the length returned in `rax` before I realized that it wasn't *the* `strlen()` that was being called and that the length was in `rcx` instead.

Comment: Micheal. I'm not sure how to type a facepalm, but realize that's what I'm doing right now :P I'm a DA, thanks for the reference as well. I'll rename my function, and return in RAX.

Answer (score 2):

According to calling convention, you have to clean up arguments you put on the stack. In this case that applies to the 5th argument to `WriteConsoleA`. Since you have a copy of original `rsp` in `rbp`, you can reload `rsp` from `rbp`, or just add 8 after the `call`.